# How do I setup kerberos authetication in Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, authentication, kerberos

I cannnot seem to find documentation on setting up Kerberos authentication on my Fedora 19 workstation. Which files and programs are involved? My Kerberos server is a corporate AD.